Error: expected a sequence of length 32 (got 44)
I am a python newbie and I am trying to create a simple wallet balance tracker for solana, I keep getting the error message: Error: expected a sequence of length 32 (got 44)
heres the code:
import solana
from solana.rpc.api import Client
from solders.pubkey import Pubkey

# Initialize the Solana client
solana_client = Client("https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com")

def get_wallet_balance(wallet_address):
    try:
        # Convert the wallet address to a PublicKey object
        wallet_pubkey = Pubkey(wallet_address)
        
        # Get the balance of the wallet
        balance_info = solana_client.get_balance(wallet_pubkey)
        
        # Extract the balance in lamports
        balance_lamports = balance_info['result']['value']
        
        # Convert lamports to SOL (1 SOL = 10^9 lamports)
        balance_sol = balance_lamports / 1e9
        
        return f"The balance of wallet {wallet_address} is {balance_sol} SOL."
    except Exception as e:
        return f"Error: {e}"

def main():
    print("Welcome to the Solana Wallet Tracker!")
    while True:
        # Ask the user for a wallet address
        wallet_address = input("Enter a Solana wallet address (e.g., '9xQeWvG816bUx9EPjHmaT23yvVM2ZWbrrpZb9PusVFin') or 'q' to quit: ")
        
        if wallet_address.lower() == 'q':
            print("Exiting the Solana Wallet Tracker. Goodbye!")
            break
        
        # Get and print the balance of the specified wallet
        result = get_wallet_balance(wallet_address)
        print(result)
        print()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


Try to update these lines:
        # Convert the wallet address to a PublicKey object
        wallet_pubkey = Pubkey.from_string(wallet_address)

        # Get the balance of the wallet
        balance_info = solana_client.get_balance(wallet_pubkey)
        
        # Extract the balance in lamports
        balance_lamports = balance_info.value

